# Function similar to xlookup in Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, xlookup

So I am looking for some Python code/function similar to Xlookup in excel.

Basically I am trying to include one new column in a dataframe (df). The values within this new column will depend on two columns of df which are time and day of week. The df looks like:
[image]

The values of this third column will come from excel sheet saved as dataframe PSA, shown here:

[image]

Now I am not sure how do I read this data values based on time (hour) and Day so that I can include in a third column. I have tried `pd.merge(df, PSA, on=['time', 'day'], how='left')` but it's not working.

Need your help.

TIA!

Comment: `melt` PSA first?

Comment: ok but still stuck with column part